# The innerText of a button won't change on reload

Tags: javascript

When I change the innerText of a button, it would work perfectly fine, but when I reload the page, it will go back to its default innerText. What I'm trying to do is when I click the button and it changes to "Remove from Favorites", I want this innerText to still be "Remove from Favorites after I reload the page.

```
function favorite(){
  if (event.target.innerText === "Add to Favorites"){
    event.target.innerText = "Remove from Favorites"
  }
  else {event.target.innerText = "Add to Favorites"}    
}

<button onClick="favorite()">Add to Favorites</button>
```

I recently just became familiar with localStorage. I played around with it, but the code still doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
function favorite(){
  localStorage.setItem("add", event.target.innerText)
  let a = localStorage.getItem("add")

  if (a === "Add to Favorites"){
    a = "Remove from Favorites"
  }
  else {a = "Add to Favorites"}    
}

<button onClick="favorite()">Add to Favorites</button>
```

Comment: You don't set the text of the button. Where is the `event.target.innerText` like the first example? Where is the `localStorage.getItem("add")` when the page loads?

Comment: The code works, it just doesn't do what you think it does.
You are just assigning some value to variable a, which you don't use anyhow.

Comment: Changing the variable a doesn't change the ```add``` value  in local storage so every time you refresh the page ```add``` value will always be the same in local storage.

Comment: Your function keeps reassigning your `a` variable, at no point are you actually updating the `innerText` off the `button`.

Comment: @digitalniweb If it doesn't do what it's intended to do, it doesn't "work".

Comment: @Barmar If you write "print 'Hello world';" but your intention was to program a Facebook with this line of code doesn't mean it doesn't work like intended. It works properly.

Comment: @digitalniweb That's ridiculous. If you're writing a calculator program, and type `+` instead of `*` in the code that's supposed to process the multiplication operator, it doesn't work properly, since it adds instead of multiplying. The technical term for this is "a bug".

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value from `localStorage` when the page loads, not when the user clicks on the button.

When you change the button you need to save the value to `localStorage`.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let fav = localStorage.getItem("favorite");
  if (fav) {
    document.getElementById("fav-btn").innerText = fav;
  }
});

function favorite(target) {
  if (target.innerText === "Add to Favorites") {
    target.innerText = "Remove from Favorites"
  } else {
    target.innerText = "Add to Favorites"
  }
  localStorage.setItem("favorite", target.innerText);
}
```

```html
<button id="fav-btn" onClick="favorite(this)">Add to Favorites</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. The only issue I have now is that sometimes I when I refresh the page, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null". Other times I do get the correct innerText.

Comment: That can't be due to any of the code I posted. It never reads `innerText` when the page loads. It only reads it when you click the button, and that can't possibly be null.